# Grails Domain: CompositeIdentity CannotRedirectException it is not a domain or has no identifier

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

My class is defined as follow:

```
class A{
    String id
    static hasMany = [b: B]
}
class B  implements Serializable {
    A a1
    A a2
    static belongsTo = [a1: A, a2: A]
    static hasMany = [a1: A, a2: A]
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['a1','a2']
    }

    equals and hashCode method...
}
```

but when I run it(Controller def scaffold = true), it says: No such property: generator for class: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.CompositeIdentity`.

Then I Generate the code of Controller and views manually, the error changed to :
Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException
Message
Cannot redirect for object [B : (unsaved)] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead

Finally I found [explicit redirect](http://www.bl-nk.net/2014/04/explicit-redirect-grails/)

and the question is solved.

**conclusion**: the composite key is not supported by plugin scaffolding.

Comment: Does it even compile? I believe `def A a1` is not correct syntax in Groovy. You can have `def a1` or `A a1` and in this case latter is correct one. You should show us full code of domain and full stacktrace of error, otherwise it's much harder to help

Comment: @droggo you are right, "def" is not necessary, but idea generated it by default.  "A a1" works too.